Android hotspot fixed DHCP MAC --> IP mapping?
I need to be assigned always the same IP address when I connect through Android Wi-Fi hotspot, but such technicality is not configurable via Android GUI. Is there a way I could configure Android hotspot to assign connected device always the same IP address from its DHCP pool (usually based on MAC address of the device)?
Most Android hotspots have 192.168.43.0/24 IP range with the hotspot having 192.168.43.1, so I would like my device to be assigned always for example 192.168.43.119.
Setting the address on the client is NOT an option as it could be in conflict with IP address assigned to another device connecting through the hotspot.

Is your phone rooted?

Yes, but if there is some possibility for not rooted as well.... :-)
